# XML parsing error(invalid token) caused by PDF

Tags: python, xml, pdf, xfa

A colleague of mine filled-in dynamic PDF form, saved and sent it to me. However due to probably some weird symbol used it did not open, neither on colleague's or my PC. It was giving *XML parsing error: not well-formed (invalid token) (error code 4)*. There was a lot of important info in that doc so I really need a way to recover it.

I tried many recommended things, such as:

- Upgrading official Adobe Acrobat Reader to the latest version. Afterwards repairing it.
- Opening with other software such as FOXIT reader, software for working with docs (Libre Office, notepad, Sublime, etc.).
- Opening with Adobe Acrobat Livecycle Design - software with which this application form (I suppose) was created.
- Using different PDF2text libraries (written in Python). As the form was dynamic this method was inefficient
- Made a post on official  Adobe Support Website  (yeah, that's the only way to get help from Adobe using free versions of software)

However I came up with zero result.

[image: error pic]

The only thing that succeed a bit was opening PDF with default Windows notepad. It showed XML-formatted code, however most of the code was encoded (on gist small part of encoded code is seen in the end, but there is much more) Was something like that:

```
%PDF-1.6
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</AcroForm 59 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 2 0 R/Names 60 0 R/Pages 235 0 R/Type/Catalog/Perms 233 0 R/StructTreeRoot 243 0 R/NeedsRendering true>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Length 4114/Subtype/XML/Type/Metadata>>stream
<?xpacket begin="ï»¿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.4-c005 78.150055, 2013/08/07-22:58:47        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
            xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/"
            xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
            xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/"
            xmlns:desc="http://ns.adobe.com/xfa/promoted-desc/">
         <dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
         <dc:creator>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>DAAD</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </dc:creator>
         <dc:title>
            <rdf:Alt>
               <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">PBF: Gutachtenformular</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Alt>
         </dc:title>
         <pdf:Producer>Adobe XML Form Module Library</pdf:Producer>
         <xmp:CreateDate>2008-08-14T09:56:29+02:00</xmp:CreateDate>
         <xmp:CreatorTool>Adobe LiveCycle Designer ES 10.4</xmp:CreatorTool>
         <xmp:MetadataDate>2017-03-17T09:14:06+01:00</xmp:MetadataDate>
         <xmp:ModifyDate>2017-03-17T09:14:06+01:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
         <xmpMM:DocumentID>uuid:d62a53c0-8974-4b14-888e-569579f416d8</xmpMM:DocumentID>
         <xmpMM:InstanceID>uuid:c097e78e-1dd1-11b2-0a00-9e91daf58acd</xmpMM:InstanceID>
         <desc:embeddedHref rdf:parseType="Resource">
            <rdf:value>G:\Z2\00- Verbindliche Formulare, Vorlagen\___Logo_fuer_Formulare_06_2015\DAAD_Globe_Logo-Supplement_eng_tl_rgb_300dpi.jpg</rdf:value>
            <desc:ref>/template/subform[1]/pageSet[1]/pageArea[1]/draw[2]</desc:ref>
         </desc:embeddedHref>
         <desc:Schema-Anmerkung rdf:parseType="Resource">
            <rdf:value>16 byte UUID in 32 chars (hexadecimal encoded)</rdf:value>
            <desc:ref>/template/subform[1]/subform[1]/field[1]</desc:ref>
         </desc:Schema-Anmerkung>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
 
<?xpacket end="w"?>
endstream
endobj
214 0 obj
<</Filter[/FlateDecode]/Length 419>>stream
H‰¼“[kÂ0Çßýg}²LŠ¦àæC7'†nÞØžB°§.,¶¥IÕáüîKÓ8[´2˜¬”^’ÿ¹äwÎa>Tåg„¡_]û”°@HÊ9z6t:`%‡>Ð³àërº%Æ‚…Á1UnnáÊiØ•M
```

I tried many different decoding tools - no success.

Comment: Can you share the pdf in question for inspection? Furthermore, how exactly does the [tag:python] tag relate to your question? Does that only refer to the use of *"different PDF2text libraries (written in Python)"* or does it indicate you hope for a solution in python?

Comment: @mkl, I was writing question-answer post, so as my solution is based on Python code - this tag is included. I will upload PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have used specific FlateDecoding method.
There is a working solution written by [Stephen Haywood](https://gist.github.com/averagesecurityguy/ba8d9ed3c59c1deffbd1390dafa5a3c2) . I checked its correctness in Python 2. Just change the PDF title to yours and run in terminal with python command. Here is the gist.

```
#!/bin/bash
import re
import zlib

pdf = open("some_doc.pdf", "rb").read()
stream = re.compile(r'.*?FlateDecode.*?stream(.*?)endstream', re.S)

for s in stream.findall(pdf):
    s = s.strip('\r\n')
    try:
        print(zlib.decompress(s))
        print("")
    except:
        pass
```